# javascript document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

What i am trying to do here is modifying the element and adding attribute (class) using JS.

JS Script

```
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clearfix div");
  x[0].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");
  x[1].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");
```

HTML Default Format

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    a lot of divs here
</div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    a lot of divs here
</div>
</div>
```

HTML Result

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="regDesign">
        <div class="regDesign"></div>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired HTML Result

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="regDesign">
        <div></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="regDesign">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: have you tried `document.querySelectorAll(".clearfix div div");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the selector as follows:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clearfix > div");
x[0].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");
x[1].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("clearfix")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Comment: Thank you sir for helping. But what if i have a lot of div below it. I want to do it dunamically. I will be changing my question sir.

Comment: @EmelioSteveMalisa You are welcome.This is done dynamically. What output are you hoping for?

Comment: Loop thru if you have a bunch of divs in the collection

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for any number of `<div>`
For adding classes, use `classList.add()` instead of `setAttribute()`

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clearfix > div");
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.add("regDesign");
}

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("clearfix")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it dynamically, even if there is more than one div in each div:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clearfix>div");
x[0].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");
x[1].setAttribute("class", "regDesign");
```

Comment: .clearfix > div, thank you sir. This does the trick. I will be looking on this and understand how this " > " works. thankssss